# react-native - Denying location access, UI does not update or respond to anything

Tags: react-native, permissions, react-native-maps

When my application loads the map, a location permission pops up, If I deny, I can only move around the map and click on a marker which will display a callout. 
The other elements of the UI which are not map related, are unusable. I can tap them and nothing happens. Even the logs don't show anything.
Also, whatever I put in shouldcomponentupdate, nothing executes, I cannot see anything not even in the logs. 
If I enable location permissions, everything starts working again.

After I deny the permission, these are the last two lines that will show in the logs:

```
01-17 15:18:52.912 11082 11082 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
01-17 15:18:53.092 11082 11122 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() end
```

I use:

"react-native": "0.50.0"

"react-native-maps": "0.17.0"

Comment: Please post your code. And what do you expect to happen? It should hide the map?

Comment: @sfratini Thank you for the help but I have managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by removing the title and message from  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION object. That view disappeared when I tapped it but I think it did not really disappear and it was capturing every other event.